# Callback for jQuery.prepend() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

is possible to add callback into prepend method? I need to wait until DOM is rebuild and then start fade animation.

```
$("body").prepend(div);
$(div).css({
  'opacity': 1
});
```

The animation is made with CSS3 transitions, so I only need to wait for DOM ready and then change the CSS opacity..

[Here is fiddle with my problem...](http://jsfiddle.net/8MFJQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an update: http://jsfiddle.net/8MFJQ/4/

prepend doesn't have a callback because the DOM is ready with the call. I'm using Jquery's [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) as well to achieve wider browser coverage.

Comment: Yeah. thats working, but I was trying to achieve same thing with CSS transitions because of it's hardware acceleration on the iPad..

Comment: Thanks..and as I am asking, whats the default value of setTimeout second parameter? 0ms?

Comment: 10ms is kind of the default. Basically if setTimeout is less than 10ms, the delay becomes 10ms

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you can do it like that `$("body").append(div).css({'opacity': 1});`. Or maybe you've to change the method for, like this `$(div).appendTo('body').css({'opacity': 1});`

Comment: I added link where you can see exactly my problem